# Custom themes for the Netbeans IDE?

Tags: php, javascript, netbeans

Looking for custom themes for the Netbeans IDE, especially dark ones!

Thanks!

Comment: needs to be community wiki or this will get closed.

Comment: how do I make it community wiki?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

http://net.tutsplus.com/freebies/themes/netbeans-twilight-theme/

---

[http://nettuts.s3.cdn.plus.org/338_netbeansFreebie/twilight.png http://nettuts.s3.cdn.plus.org/338_netbeansFreebie/twilight.png](http://nettuts.s3.cdn.plus.org/338_netbeansFreebie/twilight.png)

Comment: I see that its good for PHP, will check it out!